# "SSL connect error": unable to push to github

Tags: git, ssl, github

I'm trying to set up a git repository on a server that I have an account on.  So I first made sure that it worked on my local box (which already has git), and everything worked fine.  So I compiled git and then ran.  But when I tried to run it on the server, everything worked fine up till:

```
$ git push --set-upstream origin master
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/Elronnd/so-many-fools.git/': SSL connect error
```

This server is not maintained very frequently, as it's primarily used (by everyone except for me) just for email.  Is it possible it has to do with the version of openSSL or something?

Also:

```
$ GIT_CURL_VERBOSE=1 git push --set-upstream origin master
* Couldn't find host github.com in the .netrc file, using defaults
* About to connect() to github.com port 443 (#0)
*    Trying 192.30.252.128... * Connected to github.com (192.30.252.128) port 443 (#0)
*   CAfile: /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt
* NSS error -12286
* Expire cleared
* Closing connection #0
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/Elronnd/so-many-fools.git/': SSL connect error
```

EDIT:

When running with ssh protocol (instead of http(s)):

```
$ GIT_CURL_VERBOSE=1 git push --set-upstream origin master
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

Comment: It definitely is possible. Try to prepend the whole command with `GIT_CURL_VERBOSE=1`

Comment: Put it to the question please

Comment: You need to update openssl, yes.

Comment: zerkms: Having compiled the latest version of openSSL, and the latest version of git, I get the same thing.

Comment: I don't know how git is implemented internally - but it seems like it uses libssl through curl.

Comment: Maybe I can compile the latest version of curl?  Does it compile the libraries itself or does it rely on existing ones?

Comment: I honestly have no idea - I use distribution packages and not compile anything for ages.

Comment: Is your system clock accurate?

Comment: #lezed1: How can I find out?  Is there some program I need, or can I just telnet to a time server?